# Getting a 'SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier' while reading a CSV file

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to open a CSV file using pandas in Jupyter notebook. Unfortunately, I am getting syntax error.

I tried to google the issue but nothing worked out. I tried to change the path backslash front slash, but no use.

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv(‪"C:\Users\EYKIM\Desktop\Advertising.csv")
```

I should get into next line but getting the following error.

> File "", line 2
>       data = pd.read_csv(‪"C:\Users\EYKIM\Desktop\Advertising.csv")
>                          ^ SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier

[image]

Comment: Hi, This worked. It was because I used only single 'backslash'. Thank you for the quick response

Comment: You can go ahead..

Answer (score 2):

Backslashes in a string are the start of an escape sequence. You either need to double the backslashes to escape them, use a raw string, or change them to forward slashes.

```
data = pd.read_csv(‪"C:\\Users\\EYKIM\\Desktop\\Advertising.csv")
data = pd.read_csv(‪r"C:\Users\EYKIM\Desktop\Advertising.csv")
data = pd.read_csv(‪"C:/Users/EYKIM/Desktop/Advertising.csv")
```

Comment: This worked fine. Thank you dude.


`data = pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\EYKIM\\Desktop\\Advertising.csv")`

Answer (score 1):

Try defining the path starting from home. You can find it by running in the folder that your csv is, `pwd` in the terminal or by pressing Ctrl+L while in in the folder.

Of course don't forget to add the file at the end of the path

Comment: Thank you for the response and your time. It was the error of the single backslash. A double backslash in the path worked fine. Cheers !!

Answer (score 1):

You need to change it to:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv(‪"C:/Users/EYKIM/Desktop/Advertising.csv")
```

or

```
data = pd.read_csv(‪"C:\\Users\\EYKIM\\Desktop\\Advertising.csv")
```

or

```
data = pd.read_csv(‪r"C:\Users\EYKIM\Desktop\Advertising.csv")
```